# Restore from Deja Dup backup on Samba share (a Synology NAS)

Tags: samba, backup, deja-dup

I use Deja Dup to back up my Ubuntu system to a Synology NAS mounted as a Samba drive. Today I did a fresh installation of Kubuntu, and now I want to restore my files from backup. I can mount the Samba drive and see all the Deja Dup files in Dolphin. All the backups are in the folder named `richard-MS-7C90`:

[image]

However, I cannot use Deja Dup to restore from backup. In the "Restore From Where?" screen, I enter `smb://WORKGROUP,richardcherron@nas.local/home` for "Network Location" and `richard-MS-7C90` for "Folder":

[image]

However, after a brief pause, I get an error: "Failed to mount Windows share: Operation not permitted."

[image]

How can I restore from my backup?

Comment: I do this, and I have a semi-colon ";" after WORKGROUP, not a comma ",". Don't know if this matters.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I changed the `,` to a `;`, but I see the same symptoms. I also tried `smb://WORKGROUP;richardcherron@nas.local/homes/richardcherron` because I think `home` is a shortcut for `homes/richardcherron`, but I see the same symptoms.

Comment: I thought it might not matter. Can you access the share using `smbclient`?  Like `smbclient \\\\nas.local/homes` or even `smbclient -L nas.local`. Just wondering if you can reach the share at all.

Comment: As @OrganicMarble said, make sure you can read and write into the folder using samba. Then try under **Network Location:** `smb://WORKGROUP,richardcherron@nas.local/home/richardcherron/richard-MS-7C90` and leave the **Folder:* empty

Comment: In general, and knowing it's no help, the time to become familiar with restoring backups is when you first create the backup scheme. How else will one know it's a valid backup?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can access the share from the command line with `smbclient \\\\nas.local/homes --user=richardcherron` and my password. Then my prompt changes to `smb: \>` and I can `cd` to the backup directory and see all the Deja Dup backup files.

Comment: @user68186 I receive the same "Failed to mount Windows share: Operation not permitted" error. Maybe this is due to having a password on the Samba share?

Comment: I am out of ideas.

Comment: @waltinator Yours is a good reminder! I had recovered files under _U_buntu, but not _Ku_buntu. My system crashed, and I gave Kubuntu a try. On Ubuntu, I could use the Deja Dup file chooser to navigate to the mounted Samba share. However, on Kubuntu, I cannot see the mounted Samba share with the file chooser. I can copy the backups to my Kubuntu machine and restore. However, I hoped there was a more efficient way since  I do not need the entire file history and I can mount the share in Dolphin and command line.

Comment: @user68186 No worries! I appreciate the help! I can copy the backup folder to my local machine and restore from there. Still, it is frustrating because I should not have to copy the entire backup history to restore the files as of yesterday.

Comment: Since you can access the share, I do not know why it is not working.  I too am out of ideas. Here is a workaround to try - create a mountpoint on your system and mount the share using `cifs`. Then you can point Deja-dup at it as if it were a local drive.  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/

Comment: @OrganicMarble You did it! I have to mount outside of Dolphin (`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=richardcherron,password=xxx //nas.local/homes/richardcherron /mnt/nas/`) and navigate to that mount point.

Comment: @OrganicMarble However, I cannot create a _new_ backup with this mounted drive? But that is a new question. :) Maybe there is more _Ku_buntu-friendly backup software?

Comment: I am glad you recovered your backup!! Unfortunately I have zero experience with Kubuntu.